# R - Select unique combinations of values from within the same column

Tags: r, unique, combinations

Assuming a data frame in the following structure:

```
ColA  ColB
A     1
A     2
A     4
B     3
B     2
B     4
C     1
C     1
C     1
```

Is it possible to select all combinations of A, B and C that sum to 7 (using each of A, B & C once), for example as follows:

```
ColA  Combination1  Combination2
A     2             4
B     4             2
C     1             1
```

Alternatively, would it be better to loop through all unique combinations of A, B & C to determine their total and then column bind them? If so, how would I loop through the unique combinations of A, B & C assuming data in the structure of the first data frame?

Comment: How are you determining values of columns Combination1 and Combination2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion:

```
df <- read.table( header =TRUE,
                  text = "ColA  ColB
                          A     1
                          A     2
                          A     4
                          B     3
                          B     2
                          B     4
                          C     1
                          C     1
                          C     1")

X <- tapply(df$ColB, df$ColA, unique)
G <- expand.grid(X)
G <- G[rowSums(G)==7, ]

Combinations <- data.frame(t(G))
colnames(Combinations) <- paste0("Comb_", 1:ncol(Combinations))
```

The list `X` contains the unique values of `A`,`B`, and `C`:

```
X
#$A
#[1] 1 2 4

#$B
#[1] 3 2 4

#$C
#[1] 1
```

Then `expand.grid` builds the cartesian product `G`, i.e. the combinations of these unique values:

```
G
#  A B C
#1 1 3 1
#2 2 3 1
#3 4 3 1
#4 1 2 1
#5 2 2 1
#6 4 2 1
#7 1 4 1
#8 2 4 1
#9 4 4 1
```

After `G <- G[rowSums(G)==7,]` only the combinations with a total sum of 7 are left:

```
G
#  A B C
#6 4 2 1
#8 2 4 1
```

Finally the data in the matrix `G` is put into the data.frame `Combinations`:

```
Combinations
#  Comb_1 Comb_2
#A      4      2
#B      2      4
#C      1      1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help with this! There are 9 unique combinations, the 7 was intended as the total value of the column. How might you then go about filtering the columns returned based on the sum of values in the column?

Comment: btw you don't really need `Combinations`, do you ?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Now only the combinations with a total sum of 7 are left.

Comment: @CathG `tapply` saves you the call to `split`: `tapply(df$ColB, df$ColA, unique)`.

Comment: so `subset(x=expand.grid(tapply(df$ColB, df$ColA, unique)), A+B+C==7)` is a one-liner solution

Comment: @mra68 Thank you for your help so far :-) unfortunately the data set I'm working with errors on expand.grid because it's too large (with 108 variables in place of A / B / C repeated 1:183 times). Is there any way of filtering during the expand.grid process, or would an alternative (if unfortunately more clunky) method work better?

Comment: and @JasonMorgan - apologies, it appears I can't tag more than one person in a single comment

Comment: @jj367 you're welcome :-),  you can maybe filter out the smallest value and the largest value that make it impossible to get the right sum,whatever the other values are ?